# Codeigniter on Ubuntu not Loading Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I've recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu.. Now I'm having this strange problem with codeigniter.. My code works prefect on Widnows 7 Xampp server, but when I try to access it on ubuntu having apache2, I cannot load any model, libraries etc.

Here is my code for model

```
<?php
class Usermodel extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
       parent::__construct();
       $this->user_per_page = 8;
    }

    function getUser($id)
    {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id");
    if(intval($query->num_rows()) > 0)
    {
        $data = $query->result();
        return $data[0];
    }
    else
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my controller where i am loading model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller 
{   
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("Usermodel");
        $fb_config = array(
            'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        );

        $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
        $this->load->helper('security');
    }
}
```

I've already tried the following

**1. Changed usermodel.php to Usermodel.php
2. Changed $this-load->model("Usermodel") to $this-load->model("usermodel")**

but none seem to work

I get this fatal error when i call $this->Usermodel->getUser(1) in index() function of my controller

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in /var/www/voicebuds/application/controllers/register.php on line 19, referer: mysite**

**UPDATE**
If i put the Usermodel in config/autoload.php, it works fine.. So I must say there is some problem with loader function.

Comment: Have you checked/edited .htaccess file?

Comment: did u tried calling your model function by small letters as **$this->usermodel->getUser(1)**. Also did you changed anything in your htaccess?

Comment: @user2936213: already tried this one

Comment: @Vishwas: What could be wrong with htaccess? I don't see any issues with urls as they're working fine

Comment: try calling methods in lowercase. i.e `getuser()`

Comment: @tomexsans: please see the fatal error..! It says NON OBJECT!! which means it cannot find Usermodel

Comment: Also your model file name must be Usermodel.php

Comment: I've tried it but still no use

Comment: try to change file name to lowercase, but when loading or using the model , use it by class name. i.e `Usermodel->method()` , `load->model('Usermodel')`; this is how i did it on my ubuntu.

Comment: @tomexsans: My classname is usermodel.php, and i load model by $this->load->model("Usermodel") and call the function using $this->Usermodel->functionName() .. but it doesn't work.. As i updated the question, Usermodel works if i autoload it, so i assume there is some problem with load->model function

Comment: btw what version of CI are you using?

Comment: user_model.php as file name with User_model as class name works for me in Ubuntu 12. And i load my model in controller in lowercase - $this->load->model('user_model');

Answer (score 0):

check your model file name for model

```
<?php
// file name usermodel.php
class Usermodel extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
       parent::__construct();
       $this->user_per_page = 8;
    }

    function getUser($id)
    {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id");
    if(intval($query->num_rows()) > 0)
    {
        $data = $query->result();
        return $data[0];
    }
    else
        return null;
    }
}
```

in your controller load appropriate model using model file name

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller 
{   
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("usermodel");//your file name of model
        $fb_config = array(
            'appId'  => '454005957970086',
            'secret' => '7b8e9664cb0439f88da00007996278c7'
        );

        $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
        $this->load->helper('security');
    }
}
```

Comment: my model filename is: usermodel.php

Comment: Rename it to Usermodel.php.

Comment: @kwollaston codeigniter model **The file name will be a lower case version of your class name**

Comment: @casper123 before using `$this->usermodel->getUser(1)` just use this to check the object exist or not `echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->usermodel);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;`

Answer (score 0):

Model classes are stored in your

> application/models/

folder. They can be nested within sub-folders if you want this type of organization.

The basic prototype for a model class is this:

```
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

The file name will be a lower case version of your class name. For example, if your class is this:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Your file will be this:

> application/models/user_model.php

So please check, is your model in any sub-folder or not.

It is said to be a best practice to load models, libraries in __construct (constructor)

```
class User extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {       
         parent:: __construct();
         $this->load->model('usermodel');  
    }
}
```

I found in your controller there is not construct. try to add constructor and load usermodel there

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using __construct() in controller class.. I now first initialize model in constructor and then call in in function and its working now.!! But still I'm puzzled why load-model() didn't work for me in index() function

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller 
{   

    function __construct()
    {
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model("Usermodel");

    $fb_config = array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    );

    $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
    $this->load->helper('security');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->Usermodel->getUser(1);
        print_r($data);die;
    }
}
```